# can i use linq syntax for filteting the datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i have  a  datatable    where i  need   to  filter the  record   based  on the  condition.
  i know  we  can  do it  by using  dataview  filer  condition.

is there  any way  we  can use  linq  syntax  filter  the data table  base  on condition?

thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - just use `.Cast()` on the table's rows and you're done:

```
    var qry = from row in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
              where row.Field<string>("Name") == "abc"
              select row;
```

For a typed `DataSet`, I don't think even this is needed.

Note that LINQ **queries** the data (into a *new/independent* query) - it doesn't filter the existing table.